# Error: Missing 'angularCli.config' entry in Karma config

Tags: unit-testing, angular, ionic2, karma-jasmine, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created a project in Ionic 2 using Typescript.

When I am trying to Unit Test my Ionic 2 project with the help of Karma, I get the following error when I run the npm test command:

```
Missing 'angularCli.config' entry in Karma config
Error: Missing 'angularCli.config' entry in Karma config
    at init (D:\MyApp\node_modules\angular-cli\plugins\karma.js:8:11)
    at Array.invoke (D:\MyApp\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
    at Injector.get (D:\MyApp\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:48:43)
    at D:\MyApp\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:138:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Server._start (D:\MyApp\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:137:21)
    at Injector.invoke (D:\MyApp\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
    at Server.start (D:\MyApp\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:102:18)
    at D:\MyApp\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\test.js:33:25
    at Class.run (D:\MyApp\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\test.js:15:16)
    at Class.run (D:\MyApp\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\test.js:31:25)
    at Class.<anonymous> (D:\MyApp\node_modules\angular-cli\angular-cli\lib\models\command.js:152:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

**The karma.conf.js file:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: [
      'mocha', 'karma-remap-istanbul'
    ],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**The angular-cli.json file :**

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "name": "myapp"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.test.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

What could the issue be?